# Bash script: Read text after characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to read the text after characters in a file.

For example:

```
MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486|MPlayer|2013-08-30-i486||Multimedia;video|4508K||MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486.pet|+ffmpeg|mplayer video player|slackware|14.0||
```

I'd like to read the version of the program (in the third box):

```
2013-08-30-i486
```

How I can do this in my bash script?

Comment: The part that you would like to extract features more than once. Will they be different sometimes, i.e. does it matter which one is used?

Comment: Will you need to apply this to a just a single line, or for (possibly many) lines in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easily done with `cut`:

```
echo 'MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486|MPlayer|2013-08-30-i486||Multimedia;video|4508K||MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486.pet|+ffmpeg|mplayer video player|slackware|14.0||' | cut -d '|' -f 3
2013-08-30-i486
```

which will split on `|` and choose the 3rd field.

Comment: Or (as the OP is apparently favouring short lines, `cut -d\| -f3 file` to extract the field from a file, rather than stdin.

Comment: very easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486|MPlayer|2013-08-30-i486||Multimedia;video|4508K||MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486.pet|+ffmpeg|mplayer video player|slackware|14.0||'
[[ "$s" =~ MPlayer-([^|]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
2013-08-30-i486
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F 'MPlayer-|\\|' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
2013-08-30-i486
```

To grab 3rd field using awk:

```
awk -F '\\|' '{print $3}' <<< "$s"
2013-08-30-i486
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simple to do in AWK:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{print $3}' file
2013-08-30-i486
```

It seems that the same data is repeated in several places, so I assume that they are all OK to use...In the above line, the input is being split into fields on the `|` character and the third field is being printed. The same thing will happen for every line of input.

Comment: This option is very simple and short. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Actually [FatalError's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25389082/2088135) would be even shorter if it read from a file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `read` (all shells):

```
IFS='|' read __ __ VERSION __ < file
echo "$VERSION"
```

Another using `read -a` and Bash arrays:

```
IFS='|' read -a FIELDS < file
echo "${FIELDS[2]}"
```

Output:

```
2013-08-30-i486
```

Answer (score 1):

Through grep,

```
$ grep -oP 'MPlayer-\K[^|.]*(?=\|)' file
2013-08-30-i486
```

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486|MPlayer|2013-08-30-i486||Multimedia;video|4508K||MPlayer-2013-08-30-i486.pet|+ffmpeg|mplayer video player|slackware|14.0||' | sed -r 's/^[^|]+\|[^|]+\|([^|]+).*$/\1/'
2013-08-30-i486
```

Answer (score 1):

The `read` built-in will be most efficient for a single line:

```
IFS="|" read __ __ version __ <<< "$line"
```

although if you are processing a file full of such lines with

```
while IFS="|" read __ __ version __; do
    # do something with $version
done < file
```

it might be more efficient to use `cut`:

```
while read version; do
    # do something with $version
done < <(cut -d'|' -f3 file)
```

or `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' '{ # do something with $3 }' file
```